# Prove $\left|\begin{smallmatrix}a&b-c&c+b\\a+c&b&c-a\\a-b&b+a&c\end{smallmatrix}\right|=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ without direct evaluation

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Prove that $\begin{vmatrix}a&b-c&c+b \\
> a+c&b&c-a\\
> a-b&b+a&c
> \end{vmatrix}=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ without direct evaluation.

My attempt is as follows:-

$$R_1\rightarrow R_1-R_2$$
$$R_1\rightarrow R_2-R_3$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}-c&-c&b+a \\
c+b&-a&-a\\
a-b&b+a&c
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$C_1\rightarrow C_1-C_2$$
$$C_2\rightarrow C_2-C_3$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&-c-b-a&b+a \\
a+b+c&0&-a\\
-2b&b+a-c&c
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$R_3\rightarrow R_3+R_1$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}0&-(a+b+c)&b+a \\
a+b+c&0&-a\\
-2b&-2c&a+b+c
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$R_1\rightarrow R_1+R_2$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}a+b+c&-(a+b+c)&b \\
a+b+c&0&-a\\
-2b&-2c&a+b+c
\end{vmatrix}$$

Looks like we can't reduce it anymore, so I expanded:

Expanding with respect to second row as there is one zero in that

$$-(a+b+c)(-(a+b+c)^2+2bc)+a(-2c(a+b+c)-2b(a+b+c)$$

$$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca-2bc)+(a+b+c)(-2ca-2ba)$$
$$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

I got the result at the end but is it the good way? Honestly I am not satisified with my way, is there any set of transformations which would be better?

Please help me with your suggestions?

Comment: What's stopping you from just calculating the determinant immediately?

Comment: If you expand it directly, first of all it will be very lengthy because you will have to take care of lot of terms and in short time you can easily go wrong, I think that's why we use transformations so that we can reach end result easily.

Comment: I don't think it will be more lengthy than this, to be honest.

Comment: ok its your perspective, I am not gonna comment upon that.

Comment: A direct computation gives $$a^3+a^2 b+a^2 c+a b^2+a c^2+b^3+b^2 c+b c^2+c^3$$ which is exactly $(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

Comment: Please mention in your question if you are asked to solve this using properties of determinants (this might be the case in textbook/exam problems where it is implied) and not direct evaluation.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, yeah correct I should have mentioned that, I will just update my question.

Answer (score 2):

If $a=0$, then the determinant of your matrix is$$b^3+b^2 c+b c^2+c^3=(b+c)(b^2+c^2).$$Otherwise\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}a & b-c & b+c \\ a+c & b & c-a \\ a-b & a+b & c\end{vmatrix}&=a\begin{vmatrix}1 & \frac{b-c}a & \frac{b+c}a \\ a+c & b & c-a \\ a-b & a+b & c\end{vmatrix}\\&=a\begin{vmatrix}1 & \frac{b-c}{a} & \frac{b+c}a \\ 0 & \frac{a c-b c+c^2}a & \frac{-a^2-a b-b c-c^2}a \\ 0 & \frac{a^2+a c+b^2-b c}a & \frac{-a b+b^2+b c}a\end{vmatrix}\\&=a^3+b^3+c^3+a^2b+a^2c+ab^2+b^2c+ac^2+bc^2\\&=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2).\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

I got some very good way to solve this problem:

Multiply first column by $a$

$$\dfrac{1}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
a^2&b-c&b+c\\
a^2+ac&b&c-a\\
a^2-ab&a+b&c
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$C_1\rightarrow C_1\rightarrow bC_2+cC_3$$

$$\dfrac{1}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
a^2+b^2-bc+bc+c^2&b-c&b+c\\
a^2+ac+b^2+c^2-ac&b&c-a\\
a^2-ab+ab+b^2+c^2&a+b&c
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
a^2+b^2+c^2&b-c&b+c\\
a^2+b^2+c^2&b&c-a\\
a^2+b^2+c^2&a+b&c
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
1&b-c&b+c\\
1&b&c-a\\
1&a+b&c
\end{vmatrix}$$
$$R_1\rightarrow R_1-R_2$$
$$R_2\rightarrow R_2-R_3$$

$$\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a}\begin{vmatrix}
0&-c&b+a\\
0&-a&-a\\
1&a+b&c
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a}(ca+ab+a^2)$$

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)$$

Hope it will be useful to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

By Gaussian triangularization subtracting a multiple of the first row and from 2,3 and  then 2 from 3 yields

for $a \neq 0 ,\neq 0, a-b+c  \ne 0 $

$$mt=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b-c & b+c \\
 0 & \frac{a c-b c+c^2}{a} & \frac{-a^2-a b-b c-c^2}{a} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{(a+b+c) \left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)}{c (a-b+c)} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $a=0$, rotate b or c to position 1,1.

Even the case $$(a-b+c) =0, $$ to be handled by rotations too,
yields determinant

$$a= b-c; \det(m)= 4 b (b^2 - b c + c^2)$$

that has the required form

$$a= b-c; (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2) = 4 b \left(b^2-b c+c^2\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
p=\pmatrix{a\\ b\\ c}=ku,
\quad e=\pmatrix{1\\ 1\\ 1}
\quad\text{and}\quad [p]_\times=\pmatrix{0&-c&b\\ c&0&-a\\ -b&a&0},
$$
where $k=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$, $u$ is a unit vector and $[p]_\times$ denotes the cross product matrix such that $[p]_\times q=p\times q$ for every vector $q$. The matrix in the identity is equal to
$$
A=pe^T+[p]_\times=kue^T+k[u]_\times\ .
$$
It is the matrix representation of the linear operator
$$
Tx=\langle e,x\rangle ku+ku\times x\tag{1}
$$
with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Extend $u$ to an orthonormal basis $\{u,v,w\}$ of $\mathbb R^3$ such that $u\times v=w$. By $(1)$, we have
\begin{align*}
Tu&=\langle e,u\rangle ku,\\
Tv&=\langle e,v\rangle ku+kw,\\
Tw&=\langle e,w\rangle ku-kv.\\
\end{align*}
Therefore, with respect to the ordered basis $\{u,v,w\}$, $T$ has the matrix representation
$$
B=\left(\begin{array}{c|cc}k\langle e,u\rangle&k\langle e,v\rangle&k\langle e,w\rangle\\ \hline
0&0&k\\ 0&-k&0
\end{array}\right).
$$
It follows that
\begin{align*}
&\det A=\det T=\det B\\
&=k\langle e,u\rangle \det\pmatrix{0&k\\ -k&0}= \langle e,p\rangle k^2=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2).
\end{align*}